# Twisted error when trying to call self

Tags: python, twisted

I am getting a strange AssertionError when I run my listener. The `if` portion of logic in this class works and I took the twisted code from this tutorial:
http://krondo.com/our-eye-beams-begin-to-twist/

```
 class controlListener(object):
         counter = 20
         def count(self):
             if self.counter == 0:
                 print "Killing Process"
                 reactor.stop()
             else:
                 print self.counter, '...'
                 self.counter -= 1
                 reactor.callLater(1, self.counter)
```

The error

```
 --- <exception caught here> ---
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 429, in _continueFiring
     callable(*args, **kwargs)
   File "sponzyTwisted.py", line 17, in count
reactor.callLater(1, self.counter)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 705, in callLater
     assert callable(_f), "%s is not callable" % _f
  exceptions.AssertionError: 19 is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to provide a callable object to `callLater` [as seen in the docs](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.1.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IDelayedCall.html), and you are providing your simple int `counter` instead. You should be passing your actual method `count` as the callable, like so:

```
class controlListener(object):
         counter = 20
         def count(self):
             if self.counter == 0:
                 print "Killing Process"
                 reactor.stop()
             else:
                 print self.counter, '...'
                 self.counter -= 1
                 reactor.callLater(1, self.count)
```

Comment: Thats awesome it works but the controlListener doesnt pass priority to the printStuff reactor. Am I using the wrong callback? Id like control listenr to do one ieteration then pass to something else Which call should I use?

Comment: The callback looks to be correct to me, but I am not experienced with Twisted. Just call `reactor.callWhenRunning(controlListener().count)`